# DataError- value too long for type character varying(256) when writing Python data frame to AWS red shift

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a Python data frame to redshift . I wrote this code -

```
df.to_sql('df', redshiftEngine, index = False, if_exists = 'replace')
redshiftENgine = create_engine('skipping the details')
```

I am getting below error :

```
DataError: value too long for type character varying(256)
```

Further digging into sqalchemy documentation I found this :

```
Exception raised for errors that are due to problems with the processed data like division by zero, numeric value out of range, etc.This error is a DBAPI Error and originates from the database driver (DBAPI), not SQLAlchemy itself.
```

But I am still unsure how to deal with this error. I have 300+ columns and 3000+ rows.

Have anyone faced this before ?

Comment: I have seen this before. This is due to the column size for the column. If you have varchar sizes of same value for all the columns then it would be a nightmare to detect the column whose length needs to be increased.

Comment: Do you mean size of each column or number of total columns ? is there a way to increase character limit for each column to avoid this error ?

Comment: It is related to the size of the column. You can try changing the size of the column which is greater than 256 character long to hold a long string.